# Regular Expression Remove large portions of string

Tags: regex, powershell-3.0

I am looking to extract the name value from the output returned by the line...

```
Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer $env:computername | ? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Administrators"'} | Select -Property PartComponent
```

I would think that I would use a regular expression to trim but I am unfamiliar with their operation and (as of yet) have been unable to find instructions sufficient to complete this.

For reference, the output is something like...

```
\\My_Machine\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="My_Machine",Name="Administrator"
```

And I would like to extract 'Administrator' from that output.

Right now I'm trying...

```
$Report = Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer $env:computername | ? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Administrators"'} | Select -Property PartComponent
$Report | ForEach-Object {$_.PartComponent -match '(?<=Name=")[^"]+[^"]'
[PSCustomObject]@{Resultant_String=$Matches.Values}}
```

and I'm getting...

```
Resultant_String                                                                                                                             
{Administrator}                                                                                                                              
True
{admin}                                                                                                                                      
True
{GroupName}                                                                                                                              
True
{UserName}                                                                                                                                  
True
{CiscoHistRprtUsr}
```

Comment: So you just want to capture what is inside of the quotes directly following `Name=` yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I ended up with this.

```
$FileServer = "My_File_Server"
$LocalHostName = $env:computername
$OutPutPath = "\\$FileServer\system_information$\"
$GetAdmins = Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer $LocalHostName | ? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Administrators"'} | Select -Property PartComponent
ForEach-Object{$GetAdmins | % {if ($_ -match 'Name="(.+)"') {[PSCustomObject]@{Name=$Matches[1]}}}} | Export-Csv -Path "$OutPutPath\$LocalHostName\$ReportName.csv" -NoTypeInformation}
```

It produces a table with a name header that has the username of all the local admins extracted from the returned string.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, `(?<=Name=")[^"]+[^"]`.  What this is doing is a positive look behind for `Name="` and then any char (except `"`) in repetition and then any char that isn't `"`.  This is a little more robust, since this will still work if the `Name=` is not the last element in your string.  If `Name=` is say the first value returned, it should still only capture what is in the quotes directly following it, and not everything else until the last `"`.

Using your test example, I did some testing [here](http://rubular.com/r/XJ1grTegcG).

Comment: Cool tool.  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I tweaked the regex a little to make it a little more robust.  Now it should work if stuff is returned back to you in a different order, say `Name` and then `Domain`.  So in the future if you add things to the end or more items returned, it shouldn't break the regex and it should continue to work as expected.

Comment: Excuse me for my astounding ignorance (in my defense I did only learn of the existence of regular expressions this morning) but, how would I make practical use of this?

If I assign my output to a variable and then run a replace the text that is targeted becomes replaced, whereas a match doesn't populate the $Matches table like documentation has described.  I think I would want to run a replace on the parts that are not targeted or extract the target to a variable/table.  I'm not sure which is more correct as, like I mentioned, I am quite ignorant to the ways of regular expressions.

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to do with the data.  Without any idea what the end goal is of this string and the substring (Name) it is very hard to say use replace, or match, or this or that.  Infinite possibilities with the data.  If the only thing you want saved at the end of the day IS just NAME, then use regex to match.  If you want to manipulate the larger string, use replace.  Regex is useful for finding specific smaller parts, or verifying that a string (input) matches some set of rules or requirements.

Comment: Ultimately I'm looking to change the string so that instead of reading "Blah, blah, blah, Name=This_name" it reads This_name.

Comment: Use the regex to match and save that match off as a temp variable.  Then you can just overwrite the original with the smaller matched string.  Easier to do that then replacing all the other junk.  Use regex to find just what you want, save it, and use it as needed.  If this helps please make sure to mark the answer as useful and accept the answer so others know the solution and I get a little something for taking the time to help :)

Comment: I think I have this well enough to know I'm going down the right rabbit hole.  I added my current script incorporating you regex statement and my results.  They are still a bit wonky but I think I should be able to get them cleaned up from here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If Name is always at the end of the string, you can simply use

```
([^"]*)"$
```

Explanation here : http://regex101.com/r/yV3uD6

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

`(?<=Name=")[^"]*?(?=")`

Note that the the `?` after the `*` is important here. It makes the quantifier non-greedy (it's just a fancy way to say that it will capture as few characters as possible and never go beyond the closing `"`).

`(?:Name=")([^"]*?)(?:")`

Since the first and the last groups are non-capturing, you just have to retrieve the value of the second group (which is actually the first and only one in terms of capture) with something like `\1` or `$1`.